# Subscription web/desktop app [PYTHON]

Tags: python, django, sms, payment-gateway

Firstly pardon me if i've yet again failed to title my question correctly.

I am required to build an app to manage magazine subscriptions. The client wants to enter subscriber data and then receive alerts at pre-set intervals such as when the subscription of a subscriber is about to expire and also the option to view all subscriber records at any time. Also needed is the facility to send an SMS/e-mail to particular subscribers reminding them for subscription renewal.

I am very familiar with python but this will be my first *real* project. I have decided to build it as a web app using django, allowing the admin user the ability to view/add/modify all records and others to subscribe. What options do I have for integrating an online payment service? Also how do I manage the SMS alert functionality? Any other pointers/suggestions would be welcome.

Thank You

Comment: Please try to break up your questions in the future whenever it makes sense: don't ask about payment-service integration and SMS alerts in the same question. SO strives to reuse questions+answers and these posts make it hard to search for relevant stuff [in isolation!].

Answer (score 2):

**Payment gateway integration:**

- [Here is a detailed article](http://uswaretech.com/blog/2009/03/exploring-authorizenet-payment-gateway-options-and-integrating-it-with-django/) about how to integrate the [Authorize.net](http://www.authorize.net/) payment system into a Django project.  Authorize.net is used by a few popular Django projects, including the [Satchmo](http://www.satchmoproject.com/) e-commerce store project.
- [django-paypal](http://github.com/johnboxall/django-paypal) is a pluggable Django app which lets you connect to PayPal merchant services.

**SMS alerts:**

- [django-sms](http://code.google.com/p/django-sms/) is a Django app which is "...designed to make sending SMS text messages as simple as sending an email." so might be a good start.

**General Django**

- You didn't mention your knowledge level of Django itself; if you need to brush up on your Django skills I would highly recommend the book [Django 1.0 Website Development](http://www.packtpub.com/django-1-0-website-development-2nd-edition).

I think it's also worth pointing out that the resources I've mentioned here were all found in the first few results of a Google search for each topic.  These are the search terms I used:

- django payment gateway integration
- django paypal integration (because I knew of PayPal beforehand)
- django sms alerts

Comment: I wouldn't take django-sms too serious: it has no downloads and the documentation is a joke. It doesn't say anything about the technical side: what is behind the scenes? Naw, forget about this one.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to comment on the SMS alert part.

First, I have to admit that I'm not familiar with Django, but I assume it to be just like most other web frameworks: request based.  This might be your first problem, as the alert service needs to run independently of requests.  You could of course hack together something to externally trigger a request once a day... :-)

Now for the SMS part: much depends on how you plan to implement this.  If you are going with an SMS provider, there are many to choose from that let you send SMS with a simple HTTP request.  I wouldn't recommend the other approach, namely using a real cellphone or SMS modem and take care of the delivery yourself: it is way too cumbersome and you have to take into account a lot more issues: e.g. retry message transmission for handsets that are turned off or aren't able to receive SMS because their memory is full.  Your friendly SMS provider will probably take care of this.